# Elementary equivalence $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ in language of addition only.

Tags: logic

I am stuck on a seemingly easy question. When considering the language $\mathcal{L}=\{f\}$ where $f$ is a 2-ary function that we will interpret as $+$ in models $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},+)$.

The question is whether these models are elementary equivalent. I think they are since we are given no constant symbols like $1$ and we have no order $<$ in our language, I can't see how there could be a statement about addition that is only true in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since they are not isomorphic, I thought the only option was direct proof but I couldn't work that out either.

Is my intuition correct and is there a way out of a direct proof?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's one: for all $x\in\Bbb Q$, there exists $y\in\Bbb Q$ such that $y+y=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure because my knowledge on logic models is poor, but I believe this argument proves they're not equivalent. It only uses addition.

For every $x\in \mathbb Q$ there exists $y \in \mathbb Q$ such that $y+y=x$. The same is not true for $\mathbb Z$.

Edit: Sniped by TonyK

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by _sniped_ (and I am a native English speaker). Do you mean _swiped_, or do you mean _scooped_? In any case, I posted two minutes before you did, as you can see if you hover the mouse over the text that says "4 hours ago" or whatever.

Comment: In some internet forums, been sniped means that someone post a very similar answer to yours, just moments before you (often while you were writing your answer).

Comment: That's news to me! Thanks for the info.